# run action after customer order product

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am developing my own **module**.
I want after user ordered successfully run method like send **email**, **SMS** and etc.

**how can I do this?**

Comment: use plugin concept after @majid

Comment: You can write your custom code using `sales_order_place_after` event

Comment: Divyesh's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/local/Package/YourModule/etc/config.xml**

```
         <events>
          <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
              <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Model/observer</class>
                <method>getAlert</method>
              </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
            </observers>
          </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
```

Now  You Make `app/code/local/Package/YourModule/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Package_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function getAlert(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //whatever you want
    }
}
```

**This Is Works :-)**

Comment: thank you, How can i get order here?

Comment: $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); @majid